# Java 8 Nested loop Collectors.groupingBy

Tags: java-8

Hi I have a collection like `Collection<Object>` and object contains listOf Strings like `List<String> ids` now I want to do group by and generate a map using the key like

```
StringUtils.joinAll("|", obj.getAtt1(), id)
```

the att1 is from Object and id is from listOf String which is in the Object only.

Simply I want to implement below code into java8 Streams.

```
Map<String, List<Object>> objMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Object obj : listOfObjects) {
            for (String id : obj.getIds()) {
                String key = StringUtils.joinAll("|", obj.getAtt(), id);
                if (objMap.containsKey(key)) {
                    objMap.get(key).add(obj);
                } else {
                    List<Objects> objList = new ArrayList<>();
                    objList.add(obj);
                    objMap.put(key, objList );
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which of the gazillion `StringUtils` are you using? [This one](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) has no `joinAll` method. So I have to guess whether your `StringUtils.joinAll("|", obj.getAtt(), id)` is just an unnecessarily complicated way to do `obj.getAtt() + "|" + id` or something else.

Comment: Further, your code contains several errors. You are trying to invoke `getIds()` and `getAtt()` on `Object`. Then, you declare a `List<Objects>`. So, you want a similarly non-working code fragment using streams?

Answer (score 0):

You can use stream functions like `flatMap` and `toMap`

```java
import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

Map<String, List<Object>> objMap = listOfObjects.stream()
        .flatMap(obj -> obj.getIds().stream().map(id -> new SimpleEntry<>(obj.getAttr() + "|" + id, obj)))
        .collect(groupingBy(SimpleEntry::getKey, mapping(SimpleEntry::getValue, toList())));
```

Comment: This will return Map<Object, Object> I need Map<String, List<Object>>

Comment: Sorry, answer updated! It seems I did a last edit that screwed the answer, it should be `id -> List.of(obj)` instead of `List::of`

Comment: There is no need to collect into a `Map`, just to do a `.flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())` afterwards. You can do a single `flatMap` to `Map.Entry` elements in the first place, using either `Map.entry(…)` on up-to-date Java or `new AbstractMap. SimpleEntry(…)` on old versions. Then, don’t map to single element lists which require this complicated merge function. Keep the plain object instead and use `groupingBy` instead of `toMap` to create a map with list values.

Comment: Thanks @Holger, it looks shorter indeed, but still had to use `mapping` at the end to map the list of `Map.entry` to a list of final Object

Comment: Yes, that `mapping` step is unavoidable. But since you’re added an `import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;`, you can also use `new SimpleEntry<>(…)`